# Own function in RSQL Lite Engine in R

Tags: r, rsqlite

I found this SQL code for SAS and I want to translate it into RSQL Lite.

---

```
proc sql;
create table crspcomp as
select a.*, b.ret, b.date
from ccm1 as a left join crsp.msf as b
on a.permno=b.permno
and intck('month',a.datadate,b.date)
between 3 and 14;
quit;
```

---

The first Problem which occurred was R does not provide the intck function, which Returns the difference in months between two dates. I found a similar function (at stackoverflow) which looks like this:

```
mob<-function (begin, end) {
  begin<-paste(substr(begin,1,6),"01",sep="")
  end<-paste(substr(end,1,6),"01",sep="")
  mob1<-as.period(interval(ymd(begin),ymd(end)))
  mob<-mob1@year*12+mob1@month
  mob
}
```

I've tested the mob function outside RSQL and it works fine so far. Now I want to put the mob function into the SQL Statement written above. 
In the SQL Code I want to merge the data on permno and in addition I want to lag the data for 3 months (thats why I use the mob function).

---

The Annual_File looks like this:

```
GVKEY,datadate,fyear,fyr,bkvlps,permno
14489,19980131,1997,1,4.0155,11081
14489,19990131,1998,1,1.8254,11081
14489,20000131,1999,1,2.0614,11081
14489,20010131,2000,1,2.1615,11081
14489,20020131,2001,1,1.804,11081
```

The CRSP file looks like this

```
permno,date,ret
11081,20000103,0.1
11081,20000104,0.2
```

---

```
install.packages('DBI')
install.packages('RSQLite')


mob<-function (begin, end) {
  begin<-paste(substr(begin,1,6),"01",sep="")
  end<-paste(substr(end,1,6),"01",sep="")
  mob1<-as.period(interval(ymd(begin),ymd(end)))
  mob<-mob1@year*12+mob1@month
  mob
}

Annual_File <- "C:/Users/XYZ"
Annual_File  <- paste0(Annual_File ,".csv",sep="")

 inputFile <- "C:/Users/XYZ"
 inputFile <- paste0(inputFile.csv",sep="")

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname='CCM')

dbWriteTable(con, name="CRSP", value=inputFile, row.names=FALSE, header=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)
dbWriteTable(con, name="Annual_File", value=Annual_File, row.names=FALSE, header=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)



 DSQL <- "select a.*, b.ret, b.date 
          from Annual_File as a left join
          CRSP as b
          on a.permno=b.PERMNO
          and mob(a.datadate,b.date)
                between 3 and 14"


  yourData <- dbGetQuery(con,DJSQL)
```

Even tough I defined the function - the Error looks as follows.

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such function: mob
```

Comment: I have edited my code above. The question is basically how can I call own written functions in a RSQL Select Statement?

Comment: Is there nobody who can help me with this issue. I want to call an own written fuction within my RSQL select statement.

Is it even possible to do this?

Regargs

Comment: The `library` statements are missing, the code is dependent on a particular file path so it can't be run as is, do not put `install.packages` statements in code posted to SO (unless they are commented out).

Answer (score 1):

You can only use SQL functions in SQLite (and functions written in C).  You can't use R functions.

Also, SQLite is not very good for date handling since it has no date and time types.  Workarounds are possible with the functions SQLite provides (see Note at end) but I suggest you use the H2 database instead.  It has `datediff` built in.  Note that depending on what you want you may need to reverse the order of the last two arguments to `datediff`.

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf)

# create test data frames

Lines1 <- "GVKEY,datadate,fyear,fyr,bkvlps,permno
14489,19980131,1997,1,4.0155,11081
14489,19990131,1998,1,1.8254,11081
14489,20000131,1999,1,2.0614,11081
14489,20010131,2000,1,2.1615,11081
14489,20020131,2001,1,1.804,11081"

Lines2 <- "permno,date,ret
11081,20000103,0.1
11081,20000104,0.2"

fmt <- "%Y%m%d"

Annual_File <- read.csv(text = Lines1)
Annual_File$datadate <- as.Date(as.character(Annual_File$datadate), format = fmt)

CRSP <- read.csv(text = Lines2)
CRSP$date <- as.Date(as.character(CRSP$date), format = fmt)

# run SQL statement using sqldf

sqldf("select a.*, b.ret, b.date, datediff('month', a.datadate, b.date) diff
          from Annual_File as a 
          left join CRSP as b 
          on a.permno = b.permno and 
             datediff('month', a.datadate, b.date) between 3 and 14")
```

giving:

```
  GVKEY   datadate fyear fyr bkvlps permno ret       date diff
1 14489 1998-01-31  1997   1 4.0155  11081  NA       <NA>   NA
2 14489 1999-01-31  1998   1 1.8254  11081 0.1 2000-01-03   12
3 14489 1999-01-31  1998   1 1.8254  11081 0.2 2000-01-04   12
4 14489 2000-01-31  1999   1 2.0614  11081  NA       <NA>   NA
5 14489 2001-01-31  2000   1 2.1615  11081  NA       <NA>   NA
6 14489 2002-01-31  2001   1 1.8040  11081  NA       <NA>   NA
```

**Note:** To use SQLite use this where 2440588.5 is used to convert between R's UNIX epoch date origin and the date origin assumed by SQLite's functions.

```
library(sqldf)
try(detach("package:RH2"), silent = TRUE)  # detach RH2 if present

sqldf("select a.*, b.ret, b.date
          from Annual_File as a 
          left join CRSP as b 
          on a.permno = b.permno and 
             b.date + 2440588.5 between julianday(a.datadate + 2440588.5, '+3 months') and 
                                        julianday(a.datadate + 2440588.5, '+12 months')")
```